# Android: align a text according to button text

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` where I have a button, and below a text. I want to align the text according to the button text, i.e. that it starts at the same width from the left like the button text.

I tried using `android:layout_alignLeft="@id/myButton"` but that aligns it to the edge of the button, not of the button text.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

In my layout XML, button and text look like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Some text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/myButton"
    android:layout_below="@id/myButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Some text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this field **android:gravity="center"** into Your textview Content. You Will get the same..Its Working fine..Please Use this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I would do it in XML, but programmatically I would try

```
myTextView.setPadding(myButton.getPaddingLeft(),0,0,0)
```

Edit: Or, duh, you could just set the button's and textview's padding in xml

Answer (score 0):

What if you use a Java code:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);

    txt.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
    btn.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it programatically from your code.. 
Code is as follows.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rParams = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView)).getLayoutParams();
rParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.myButton); // Or you can also add other rules like -- RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE or whatever you want to do. Check our Relative layout API docs.
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView)).setLayoutParams(rParams);
```

You can also get the margins and paddings and also text alignments like..

```
((TextView))findViewById(R.id.myTextView)).setTextAlignment((Button))findViewById(R.id.myButton).getTextAlignment));
```

// Alternative code of above

```
myTextView.setTextAlignment(myButton.getTextAlignment());
```

same thing goes with margins and padding.